# Changes to CSS are not reflected in the d3.js site

Tags: d3.js

If I make changes to my css file and reload/refresh my d3.js driven page, the css changes are not shown. The only way to show the css changes is to clear the browser cache. This problem doesn't happen with other web pages that I edit the sites css. It seems there is something unique with using d3.js that holds onto the old css file, unless the cache is cleared.

Since I can't expect users to clear their cache each time, prior to loading my d3.js driven page, how can I ensure they get my css change?

**The d3.js Site Structure:**

index.php brings in d3.js in the head

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3/d3v428.js"></script>
```

index.php brings in a json file in some jquery that creates a d3chart. The chart is a structure of php pages in the json file. Each php page has a link to the css file in its head.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Snipet of the json file (each .php file has a link to the style.css file; changes to css in this file only show if I clear the browser cache)

```
[
{
    "id": "0",
    "title": "Page1",
    "asChildText": "null",
    "url": "1.php",
    "parentId": "null",
    "children": [
        {
            "id": "53",
            "title": "Page21",
            "asChildText": "Let's begin!",
            "url": "21.php",
            "parentId": "0",
            "children": [
                {
                    "id": "1",
                    "title": "Page16",
                    "asChildText": "Step1",
                    "url": "16.php",
                    "parentId": "53",
                    "children": [
```

Also the css file not used by the php pages in the json file do show changes to the css on reload. So it seems the json is connected to the css not updating.

Thanks

Comment: Try referencing your css files like `index.css?v=1`... I had a similar issue before and this fixed it

Comment: I added ?v=1 to the css file name, but it only worked once. After making a second change and reloading the page, the css did not update. I changed a border from 2px to 5px and firebug even shows the 2px still.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow the path to the css file became lost/confused with the json file. By adding a ./ in front of the reference to the css file solved the problem. I can alter the css, refresh the browser and see the changes.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need this line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" type="text/css" />
```

The reason for the "./" bit is explained below:

Single dot is for current directory.The double dot is for parent directory:

```
./ = current
../ = parent
```

Hope that helps :)